# When jobExecutionVetoed of JobListener will be execured in Quartz Scheduler?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

When jobExecutionVetoed of JobListener will be execured in Quartz Scheduler?? What is the use of jobExecutionVetoed method??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's say we have a job J and trigger T.

We have a method in TriggerListener vetoJobExecution(). This method is executed when the trigger is just fired. So, with this we can thereby control
whether to execute or dismiss the job associated with the trigger. If we want to dismiss the job , then we should return true from this method.

As soon as ,we returned from this method, "jobExecutionVetoed()" method inside our joblistener will be executed to intimate that the job execution has been banned(vetoed).